# pandas using qcut on series with fewer values than quantiles

Tags: pandas, quantile

I have thousands of series (rows of a DataFrame) that I need to apply qcut on. Periodically there will be a series (row) that has fewer values than the desired quantile (say, 1 value vs 2 quantiles):

```
>>> s = pd.Series([5, np.nan, np.nan])
```

When I apply `.quantile()` to it, it has no problem breaking into 2 quantiles (of the same boundary value)

```
>>> s.quantile([0.5, 1])
0.5    5.0
1.0    5.0
dtype: float64
```

But when I apply `.qcut()` with an integer value for number of quantiles an error is thrown:

```
>>> pd.qcut(s, 2)
...
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 5.,  5.,  5.]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg
```

Even after I set the `duplicates` argument, it still fails:

```
>>> pd.qcut(s, 2, duplicates='drop')
....
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

How do I make this work? (And equivalently, `pd.qcut(s, [0, 0.5, 1], duplicates='drop')` also doesn't work.)

The desired output is to have the `5.0` assigned to a single bin and the `NaN` are preserved:

```
0     (4.999, 5.000]
1                NaN
2                NaN
```

Comment: What's your desired output for pd.qcut(s, 2)? You only have 1 unique value and why do you want to create more than 1 bins?

Comment: I'm extracting a very specific case to address. In reality I have thousands of Series, all of which I need to cut. But qcut() runs into problem with an outlier row like this. I modified the question with the desired output.

Comment: surround the `qcut` with a `try-except` block to catch the faulty Series (Be specific enough to only get the ones too short) and deal with the ones too short sem-manually

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I am getting the same error and can't find a solution

Comment: No, no solution is known to the original problem as of 2/21/2018

Answer (score 7):

Ok, this is a workaround which might work for you.

```
pd.qcut(s,len(s.dropna()),duplicates='drop')
Out[655]: 
0    (4.999, 5.0]
1             NaN
2             NaN
dtype: category
Categories (1, interval[float64]): [(4.999, 5.0]]
```

Comment: Adding duplicates='drop' did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try filling your object/number cols with the appropriate filling ('null' for string and 0 for numeric)

```
#fill numeric cols with 0
numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['number']).columns
df[numeric_columns] = df[numeric_columns].fillna(0)

#fill object cols with null
string_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
df[string_columns] = df[string_columns].fillna('null')
```