# “For Loop” User Define function

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create a user defined function with 1 input (“Port”) and it should give me a list of 371 float, however, now I am getting only 1 element in the list. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d') 
 
def function (port): 
    for year in range(1990,2021,1): 
        for month in range(1,13,1): 
            if year == 1990 and month == 1: 
                pass 
            else: 
                y = [] 
                 
                a = df 
                a = a.set_index('date') 
                 
                a = a[a.index.year == year]  
                a = a[a.index.month == month - 1] 
                 
                 
                a.loc['Volatility'] = a.std()  
                 
                a = a.T 
                 
                a['Portfolio'] = pd.qcut(a['Volatility'], q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1],\ 
                                         labels=['1','2','3','4','5']).astype(int) 
                     
                port = a[a['Portfolio'] == port]  
                port.sort_values("Volatility") 
                 
                b = port.index 
                 
                ############################################################# 
                 
                c = df 
                c = c.set_index('date') 
                 
                c = c[c.index.year == year]  
                c = c[c.index.month == month] 
                 
                c = c[b] 
                c = c.T 
                c += 1 
                c["returns"] = (c.product(axis=1) - 1) 
                C_r = c['returns'].sum() 
                 
                y.append(C_r) 
                 
        return y 
 
p = function(1)
```

Comment: You should define `y = []` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you initialize `y` as empty array inside the loop. So it will become `[]` in every epochs. In order solving your problem, you just need to initialize the empty array before the loop.

```
y = []
for year in range(1990,2021,1): 
        for month in range(1,13,1): 
            if year == 1990 and month == 1: 
                pass 
            else: 
                .....
                y.append(...)
```

You can also simplify the conditional statement by just do

```
if not (year == 1990 and month == 1):
```

So you can get rid the `else` and `pass` since they aren't necessary.

Comment: thanks! I have edited my code to your specifications, however, now I am facing the issue of:
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg 

Do you have any solution to this? Thanks Dhana!

Comment: This line: 
````a['Portfolio'] = pd.qcut(a['Volatility'], q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1],\ 
                                         labels=['1','2','3','4','5']).astype(int)```

Comment: @WillieWong Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050696/pandas-using-qcut-on-series-with-fewer-values-than-quantiles

Comment: Dhana really appreciate your help! I will still need further explore because it’s still not achieving what I want

Comment: Hi @WillieWong . As you already got your array `y` problem solved, would you mind giving this answer an upvote? Also, if you really helped by this answer, could you accept this answer as well?